# How to convert id data which i recieve using useParams to only number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-hooks

JsonData

```
[
{
      "id": "2",
      "name": "Ajay",
      "role": "Employee",
      "department": "Accounts Department",
      "ratings": "4",
      "joiningdate": "2 Jan 2021"
}
]
```

This is the App

```
<React.Fragment>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/employee/:id" element={<Employee />} />
      </Routes>
</React.Fragment>
```

Inside employee component i am using

let empId=useParams()

i get empID but its in this format {id:"2"}

what changes should i do to make only 2 so that i can to pass in api req as below

```
axios
      .get(`http://localhost:8000/EmployeeData/${empId}`)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Simply access it like ```empId.id``` in your call request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can destructure object from useParams:

```
const {id:empId} = useParams();
```

or you can simply use dot notation in get()

```
.get(`http://localhost:8000/EmployeeData/${empId.id}`)
```

Comment: the id will be a string that should be converted to a number first before making the request.

Comment: if you just want to check if id is number, i suggest to use regex in Route (`/EmployeeData/:id(\\d+)`) but i dont see any problem why it shouldnt be as string, because you imediataly making string from that in template literal

Answer (score 1):

The data type of `empId` is an object so you can get the id with `empId.id`

[Please find the reference here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mjM4C.png)

Answer (score 1):

Convert the id to number `Number(res.data.id)` `Number("123")`

Answer (score 0):

you can use parseInt(res.data.id) or Number(res.data.id)